# StringVar not writing to file help python 3 tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, file, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter import Button
from tkinter import Entry 
from tkinter import Label
from tkinter import StringVar

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Tech organizer 1.0")
root.geometry ("230x113")
root.configure(background= "lightblue")

def savebt():
    hyee = hye.get()
    hyeee= str(hyee)
    important = open("file.txt","w")
    important . write (hyeee)
    important . close ()


def plc():

    def savebt ():
        hyee = hye.get()
        hyeee= str(hyee)
        important = open("file.txt","w")
        important . write (hyeee)
        important . close ()
        print(hye.get())


    plca = tk.Tk()
    plca.title ("pc & laptop components")
    plca.geometry ("850x560")
    plca.configure(background= "lightgrey")
    global itemlocation
    global itemlocation
    global snpn
    global var_1
    global item 
    global hye
    hye = StringVar()




    Entry (plca , textvariable = hye).grid(row = 5 , column = 5)
    #Entry (plca,textvariable = seralnumberpartnumber1, width =         30).grid(row = 10,column = 11)
    #Entry(plca,textvariable = itemlocation1, width = 30 ).grid(row = 10, column = 12)
    Button (plca, text= "save", command = savebt).grid(row = 11, column= 12)

def lsl():
    lsla = tk.Tk()
    lsla.title ("laptop storage location")
    lsla. geometry ("850x560")
    def item ():
        pass


    def ane ():
        pass

    def laptopmodel():
        pass

    def storedlocation():
        pass

    Entry(lsla, textvariable = item ).grid(row = 2, column = 2)

    Entry(lsla,textvariable = laptopmodel, width = 30).grid(row = 2, column = 3)

    Entry(lsla, textvariable = storedlocation, width = 30).grid(row = 2, column = 4)

    Button(lsla, text = "Add New Entry", command = ane).grid(row = 2,column = 5)





def psl():
    psla = tk.Tk()
    psla.title ("phone storage location")
    psla.geometry ("850x560")
    psla.configure(background= "lightgrey")
    def ane ():
    pass 



    def item ():
        pass


    Button (psla,text = "Add Entry",command = ane).grid(row=3,column=4)

    Entry (psla ,textvariable = item).grid(row=2,column=3)






def otsl():
    otsla = tk.Tk()
    otsla.title ("other tech stuff location")
    otsla.geometry ("850x560")
    otsla.configure(background= "lightgrey")

    def ane ():
        pass

    Button(otsla, text= "Add New Entry", command = ane)






Button (root,text="pc & laptop components",command = plc).grid(row=1,column=4)
Button (root,text="laptop storage location", command= lsl ).grid(row=2,column= 4)
Button (root, text="phone storagelocation",command= psl).grid(row=3,column=4)
Button (root, text= "other tech stuff location",command = otsl).grid(row=4,column=4)
root.mainloop()
```

I am making this code as a beginner and the def plc that is the one I am having trouble with. so when you run it then you will need to click the first button and type something in the box then click save. once you have clicked save you should check it you have a file called "file.txt" then when you open it you should see if what you wrote in the box is there

Comment: I am also using python 3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define your Entry widget like:

```
entry = Entry (plca , textvariable = hye)
entry.grid(row = 5 , column = 5)
```

after that to get current text from widget Entry you need to use get function on that widget:

```
def savebt ():
    hyee = entry.get() # use get function on widget not variable
    hyeee= str(hyee)
    important = open("file.txt","w")
    important.write (hyeee)
    important.close()
```

Comment: Thank you so much i been trying this for 2 days. It worked